# Azure AD -- How to only allow MFA configuration from a trusted network?

Tags: multi-factor, azure

Hopefully someone as an idea...

In Azure AD, how can we allow MFA setup by a user but only allow that configuration to occur on a trusted network? We have trusted networks defined but everything we have tried does not prevent MFA setup from outside those trusted networks.

For example, if I set MFA to Enabled, then how do we prevent the user from setting it up at home vs forcing setup from the office.

thanks

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to achieve here - you want to restrict the origin from where your users can set up MFA?

Comment: That is correct.  We don't want to allow users to set up MFA initially unless they are on a defined trusted network.  So if they are off a trusted network and haven't completed the MFA setup then they have no access.  If they complete the MFA setup on a trusted network then they are good to go.  -- thanks

Comment: I've just checked if i remembered that right, but it seems you can restrict access on azure for specific ip ranges - wouldn't this be a way to implement this? 

block access to the mfa-service from everywhere but your office-ip-range..

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions